# How to execute ADB commands within an app

Tags: android, adb

I've got a partially rooted android device. By partial root, I mean that I can only run root commands through ADB. I've figured out how to run these commands locally from within a terminal emulator on the device itself. My question is, how would I go about writing the code for an Android application that executes an ADB command (or multiple commands) from a button press? I can't find anything that explains how to run direct ADB commands through an app interface. Just to clarify, anything that involves "su" will not work on this device. It ***only*** accepts ADB input for root access.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it works on Android, but have you tried this:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("adb do something as root");
```

If you provide more info about what exactly you need to use adb for in this manner, there may be a better workaround. It is very unlikely you actually need this behavior in app, and I believe it would be generally frowned upon. It sounds like you want your app to have root, but this seems like a very unportable and unnecessary approach.

Comment: I'm trying to use an "rm -rf" command for files within the /data/data/ folder. If I try running a command issued for anything within that folder without using an ADB shell, I get access denied. I'll give your idea a try though and see if it does what I need it to.

Comment: Which files and why? If they are something generated by your program or a system call, there may be a proper corresponding call to remove them without having to do it manually. Generally speaking, Android wants you to either 1) use internal "package" memory for files, or 2) request external writes permissions and use the sd card (or the emulated card if there is no physical).

Comment: Basically I'm trying to recreate an application like "Clean Master" to remove cache folders with one tap for all applications. I've created shell scripts to do this already, so now I would like to create an app to do it on the phone-side instead of through actual USB debugging ADB.